# A way to say "in any direction" with the phrase "all 360 angles"?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

> The casters allow the chair to rotate freely.
>
> The casters allow the chair to rotate ___ all 360 angles.

I am wondering how to say this grammatically? I think "to" and "in" are ungrammatical and even if they were grammatical, the sentences wouldn't make sense, because there's more than 360 angles in a circle?

Is there a way to say "in any direction" with "all 360 angles" or "360 angles" or "360 degrees"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct phrasing would be

The casters allow the chair to rotate 360 degrees.

It is not correct to say “360 angles.” There are always an infinite number of angles. Even a chair that can only rotate 30 degrees has an infinite number - rotate it 15 degrees, or rotate it 15.1 degrees, or rotate it 15.01 degrees, or rotate it 15.001 degrees, and so forth. This doesn’t convey anything about how far the chair can rotate.

Degrees are one way of measuring angles. 360 degrees covers the entire circle. (But so does 2*pi radians, and there are other possible measurements of angles.)

You don’t need any preposition because “360 degrees” directly modifies “rotate” and explains the rotation the chair is capable of doing.

It would be okay to say “all 360 degrees,” but the “all” isn’t really necessary because “360 degrees” already means “the entire circle.”

Answer (score 0):

As SegNerd says, you can use "rotate 360 degrees." Another option is "rotate **through** 360 degrees." Either one is grammatically correct.

But *any* option that introduces the idea of measuring the extent of rotation (via degrees, radians, or any other measurement) changes the meaning of the sentence. It is possible to have some device, like a ship's wheel, that can rotate through an entire circle or even more: 360, 720, 1080 degrees of rotation or more. But all of these rotations imply a maximum, with an eventual stop.
In contrast, the individual casters (and the chair itself) rotate **without restriction.** It is theoretically possible for the objects to rotate (counter)clockwise *forever*, and there is no physical reason why they would be prevented from doing so. This is what "rotate freely" means in your original sentence.